# Error when trying to sort a column in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm getting this error when trying to sort a column in R markdown:

```
Error in xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
```

Specifically, the error is reffering to this line in the code:

```
sorted_data1<-filtered_data[order(-filtered_data[, sort_column1]), ]
```

Here is the entire block of code:

```
{r, out.width=c('50%', '50%'), fig.show='hold'}

data_column<-6

sort_column1<-6
sort_column2<-4

name_column<-1

year<-"2021"

filtered_data<-data[data$year==year,]

sorted_data1<-filtered_data[order(-filtered_data[, sort_column1]), ]
sorted_data2<-filtered_data[order(-filtered_data[, sort_column2]), ]

transposed_data1<-t(sorted_data1[, data_column])
transposed_data2<-t(sorted_data2[, data_column])

names1<-t(sorted_data1[, name_column])
names2<-t(sorted_data2[, name_column])

margins<-par(mar=c(10,5,2,2))

barplot(transposed_data1, 
        main="CO2 Emissions per country",
        names.arg = names1,
        las=2)

barplot(transposed_data2, 
        main="CO2 Emissions per country (sorting: Population)",
        names.arg = names2,
        las=2)

rm(margins)
```

How do I solve this? Thanks in advance!

I have tried checking the data set for faulty values and likewise but the columns used from the data set all contain numerical values so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Is `-filtered_data` a tibble? If so, try `-filtered_data[[sort_column1]]` instead.

Comment: Here's why that worked: with `base::data.frame` there is a little-known third argument to `[` called `drop=TRUE`. When you call `dat[,ind]` and that results in a single column, then R silently simplifies the return value to a vector; you can use `dat[,ind,drop=F]` to always return a frame even if 1 column. On the other hand, `tibble` and `data.table` both also inherit `"data.frame"` but override the behavior of `[`, both always always always return a frame-like structure, not a vector. Using `[[` will always (with all three variants) return a single column as a vector.